# Is it possible to add a stroke to a TextBlock

Tags: xaml, expression-blend-4

I've been searching around and haven't found an answer on how to do this.

Is there any way to add a stroke to `TextBlock` in Expression Blend 4.0? I have to mimic text that was originally done in Flash and the text has to be changed dynamically so I can't use an image of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, is no. You can not just apply a `Stroke` to a `TextBlock`

However, there is the ability to utilize a part of the [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to "draw" or Format your Text to Geometry data which you could then apply a `Stroke` to it as a `Path` even if it is dynamic. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details you will likely find useful and an example of exactly what you're looking for.

Hope this helps.